# Select text between two strings except with custom escape character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use regex to select all strings surrounded with `{{` and `}}`, but ignoring if it is wrapped with `[{{` and `}}]`. Here is what I have come up with: `/(?!\[){{(.*?)}}(?!])/gm`.

My issue is that in some cases there could be three curly braces instead of two, and my solution is only working with two braces.

Expected results are as follows:

`foo{{baz}}bar` => {{baz}}

`foo[{{baz}}]bar` => nothing

`foo{{{baz}}}bar` => {{{baz}}}

`foo[{{{baz}}}]bar` => nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use alternation for this problem, with regular expression:

```
\[{?{{.*?}}}?\]|({?{{.*?}}}?)
```

- `\[{?{{.*?}}}?\]` What you are not interested in. Matched but not captured.
- `({?{{.*?}}}?)` What you are interested in. Matched and captured.

The results are captured in the capture group. You can try the regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/Y7Mp0r/1).

---

Alternatively you can modify your original regular expression to:

```
(?!\[{?){{(.*?)}}}?(?!}?])
```

The issue with your original expression was the absence of the optional third `}` bracket.

You can try this regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/Y7Mp0r/2).